# TYPO3 Database migration from fluidcontent to flux

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to switch from fluidcontent to flux by removing the obsolete fluidcontent.
As mentioned in here https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent/issues/424,

you have to change the CType for all fluidcontent objects in the tt_content table from `fluidcontent_content` to `extensionnamewithoutunderscores_templatenamewithoutunderscores`.
Is there a migration script or a SQL statement available for this?

The tablename without Undescores is the filename. Why and where do i need the id of the `flux:form`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A colleague made a SQL statement, which converts all fluidcontent CTypes to the correct flux value:

```
UPDATE tt_content 
 SET CType = LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(tx_fed_fcefile, 'YourNamespace.YourExtension:', 'flux_'), '.html', ''))
 WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content';
```

You only have to change `YourNamespace.YourExtension`. You can find the right wording for `YourNamespace.YourExtension` in the tx_fed_fcefile row.

For some reasons i had to replace the CType to `flux_templatenamewithoutunderscores` not to `extensionnamewithoutunderscores_templatenamewithoutunderscores`

Comment: maybe your own extension was created but not installed?

Comment: The flux_* causes the use of the master branch of the flux extension. In the development branch, it is yourextension_*. https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1542

Comment: flux 9.1.0+ uses `yourextension_` as prefix.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the linked page:
You will need some (one for each CE you defined) queries like

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'myextension_button'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'Vendor.MyExtension:Button.html'
```

you might need a list of used CEs (with count and ignoring deleted and hidden):

```
SELECT tx_fed_fcefile,count(*) 
  FROM tt_content
  WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
  GROUP BY tx_fed_fcefile
```

Comment: This is going in the right direction, thanks. But i would love to have an automated statement/script, so i do not have to check agains all CEs.

Comment: so the neccessary string functions are available in SQL it would be easier to do it in PHP: you need to split the string in the field `tx_fed_fcefile', lowercase it, remove underscores and concatenate again. But writing either PHP or even SQL might take longer than executing some queries by hand in the SQL console (of a GUI where you can edit the last query). (list available in edited answer)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183681/typo3-database-migration-from-fluidcontent-to-flux-goes-wrong

Answer (score 2):

@kimomat's query is actually really good.
I just added in some spice in case you have more than one provider extensions installed/used.

```
UPDATE tt_content 
 SET CType = LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(tx_fed_fcefile, 'YourNamespace.YourExtension:', 'extensionnamewithoutunderscores_'), '.html', ''))
 WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content' AND `tx_fed_fcefile` LIKE 'YourNamespace.YourExtension%';
```

- Run the query for each provider extension.
- What to use for `YourNamespace.YourExtension` can also be gotten from the `ext_localconf.php` file of your provider extension.
- For example if my extension's name/key is **my_provider**, then `extensionnamewithoutunderscores_` will be `myprovider_`

A complete working article on how to do this fluidcontent to flux migration can be found here.
https://sigalambigha.home.blog/2020/04/29/how-to-migrate-fluidcontent-to-flux/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a unique answer, but it may be helpful for you all to have a specific application what it looks like for a particular situation. In this case it is an upgrade of `Flux` and other extensions on a site using `fluidbootstraptheme`.

## First check what needs to be updated.

I ran this SQL in `PhpMyAdmin`

```
SELECT tx_fed_fcefile,count(*) 
  FROM tt_content
  WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
  GROUP BY tx_fed_fcefile
```

For my particular website this resulted in...

[image]

## Make needed database updates

Now run these SQL statements in the database to fix each of the things that need updating...

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_button'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:Button.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_carousel'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:Carousel.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_embedvideo'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:EmbedVideo.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_imagegallery'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:ImageGallery.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_modallight'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:ModalLight.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_pageheader'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:PageHeader.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_row'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:Row.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_simpleresponsiveimage'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:SimpleResponsiveImage.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_tabs'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:Tabs.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_threecolumn'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:ThreeColumn.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_thumbnailbox'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:ThumbnailBox.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_twocolumn'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:TwoColumn.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'fluidbootstraptheme_well'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'FluidBT.Fluidbootstraptheme:Well.html'
```

```
UPDATE tt_content
    SET CType = 'netchd_mycontentelement'
    WHERE CType = 'fluidcontent_content'
      AND tx_fed_fcefile = 'rapidfyre_netchd:MyContentElement.html'
```

## If updating to `Flux` > 6 don't forget to run `Flux` upgrade script

After updating doing the SQL updates mentioned above, some of the content still wasn't showing up in the `ThreeColumns` and other `fluidbootstraptheme` content elements that had nested content. So I went to the extension in the backend and **ran the update script in flux** and it seemed to fix it... the results were

```
tt_content:713 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:599 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:612 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:167 on page 38 has new colPos 22001
tt_content:168 on page 38 has new colPos 22002
tt_content:169 on page 38 has new colPos 22002
tt_content:417 on page 1 has new colPos 41500
tt_content:276 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:264 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:277 on page 166 has new colPos 28501
tt_content:286 on page 166 has new colPos 28502
tt_content:288 on page 166 has new colPos 28502
tt_content:289 on page 166 has new colPos 28502
tt_content:294 on page 173 has new colPos 32701
tt_content:328 on page 173 has new colPos 32701
tt_content:330 on page 1 has new colPos 27501
tt_content:300 on page 166 has new colPos 28502
tt_content:313 on page 17 has new colPos 31201
tt_content:314 on page 17 has new colPos 31202
tt_content:315 on page 17 has new colPos 31203
tt_content:326 on page 1 has new colPos 27501
tt_content:329 on page 173 has new colPos 32702
tt_content:341 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:333 on page 173 has new colPos 32702
tt_content:337 on page 186 has new colPos 33602
tt_content:334 on page 186 has new colPos 33601
tt_content:338 on page 186 has new colPos 33602
tt_content:339 on page 186 has new colPos 33602
tt_content:354 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:358 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:387 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:360 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:388 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:699 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:698 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:487 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:371 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:372 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:392 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:386 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:436 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:389 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:397 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:398 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:414 on page 1 has new colPos 41500
tt_content:415 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:416 on page 1 has new colPos 41500
tt_content:418 on page 1 has new colPos 41500
tt_content:419 on page 1 has new colPos 41500
tt_content:430 on page 1 has new colPos 41500
tt_content:435 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:438 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:437 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:441 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:457 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:595 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:479 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:484 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:480 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:483 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:495 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:526 on page 230 has new colPos 52802
tt_content:529 on page 230 has new colPos 52801
tt_content:536 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:545 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:567 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:594 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:546 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:568 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:569 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:578 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:583 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:584 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:590 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:593 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:597 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:598 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:600 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:609 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:601 on page 250 has new colPos 60401
tt_content:602 on page 250 has new colPos 60401
tt_content:603 on page 250 has new colPos 60402
tt_content:607 on page 250 has new colPos 60402
tt_content:608 on page 250 has new colPos 60402
tt_content:610 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:620 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:628 on page 252 has new colPos 62701
tt_content:631 on page 252 has new colPos 62702
tt_content:636 on page 252 has new colPos 62702
tt_content:638 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:643 on page 253 has new colPos 64102
tt_content:647 on page 253 has new colPos 64601
tt_content:648 on page 253 has new colPos 64602
tt_content:649 on page 253 has new colPos 64101
tt_content:654 on page 139 has new colPos 65301
tt_content:655 on page 139 has new colPos 65302
tt_content:670 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:697 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:689 on page 240 has new colPos 68802
tt_content:690 on page 240 has new colPos 68801
tt_content:691 on page 240 has new colPos 68803
tt_content:700 on page 1 has new colPos 27503
tt_content:711 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:712 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
tt_content:714 on page 1 has new colPos 27502
```