# TYPO3 Database migration from fluidcontent to flux goes wrong

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I already tried to migrate everything with the help of this post:

[TYPO3 Database migration from fluidcontent to flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755107/typo3-database-migration-from-fluidcontent-to-flux?fbclid=IwAR1fnfXlcn7TI14L5eCAR2qtRpz2wEre_KrnvUEqCVfCkAhkiAXyK7A13vA)

My problem now is, that I have container-templates which all end up empty after changing the CType. Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: Please give more detail about your problem

Comment: i solved it. i forgot to edit the columns

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had to update the colPos.
Like:

```
UPDATE `tt_content` SET colPos =  ((tx_flux_parent * 100) + 0) WHERE tx_flux_column = "column";
```