# "Flux could not extract a Flux definition" error in fluidbootstraptheme after migration from fluidcontent to flux 9.2.0 and composer TYPO3 8.7 to 9.5

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

## The Problem

I’ve `composer` upgraded from `TYPO3 8.7` to `TYPO3 9.5` and uninstalled `fluidcontent` and migrated to using `flux`. Here's my extension versions...

- `flux 9.2.0`
- `fluidpages 5.0.0`
- `vhs 5.2.0`
- `fluidbootstraptheme` *(using latest version and fixed a number of errors locally since it's not maintained now)*

Now I am getting this error...

> Flux could not extract a Flux definition from "/home/username/public_html/typo3conf/ext/fluidbootstraptheme/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/NavigationList.html". Check that the file exists and contains the necessary flux:form in the configured section "Configuration"

## The Code: Configuration section in NavigationList.html

```
    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="navigationlist" options="{group: 'Navigation', sorting: '50', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/NavigationList.png\')}'}">
            <flux:form.sheet name="display">
                <flux:field.checkbox name="addWell"/>
                <flux:field.checkbox name="zeroPadding"/>
                <flux:field.input name="class"/>
            </flux:form.sheet>
            <flux:form.sheet name="items">
                <flux:form.section name="items">
                    <flux:form.object name="header">
                        <flux:field.input name="text"/>
                        <flux:field.input name="class"/>
                    </flux:form.object>
                    <flux:form.object name="item">
                        <flux:field.input name="text"/>
                        <flux:field.input name="tooltip"/>
                        <flux:field.input name="icon" eval="trim">
                            <flux:wizard.link activeTab="file"/>
                        </flux:field.input>
                        <flux:field.input name="target">
                            <flux:wizard.link activeTab="page"/>
                        </flux:field.input>
                        <flux:field.input name="class"/>
                    </flux:form.object>
                    <flux:form.object name="divider">
                        <flux:field.input name="class"/>
                    </flux:form.object>
                </flux:form.section>
            </flux:form.sheet>
        </flux:form>
    </f:section>
```

## What I've already done

- I have manually run all the DB updates to migrate from `fluidcontent` to `flux` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755107/typo3-database-migration...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755107/typo3-database-migration-from-fluidcontent-to-flux)
- I've reviewed this issue https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1542
- I ran the `flux` update tool within the TYPO3 install tool and content showed up in the backend in their appropriate columns again
- I made `TYPO3 8.7` composer-based install and then upgraded via composer to `TYPO3 9.5` and now am getting the error mentioned above
- I have tried to find answers in `Google`, `StackOverflow` and `Slack` but no go

**HELP, what's wrong with the Configuration section of code above??**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comment I got from Claus Due (the primary Flux developer) on TYPO3 Slack in the Flux channel...

> The error [Flux could not extract a Flux definition...] usually means the template file itself can't be parsed correctly (could be elsewhere than the `Configuration` section). You may be able to see a more specific error if you make an ad-hoc FLUIDTEMPLATE typoscript object to render that file.
>
> Although it doesn't help you today, that particular error message will be removed in the next version of Flux and the "real" error will be passed through.
>
> Setting your TYPO3 "context" to Development should cause any Fluid parsing errors (like invalid argument etc.) to be thrown as exceptions when Flux tries to parse the template.

So in response to this, I set `TYPO3_CONTEXT='Development'` in my `.env` and was then able to see much more meaningful errors. It turned out I needed to do these two things though of course it could be different in someone else's particular case where it's some other extension causing the issue.

1. Update the deprecated fluid statement `<f:case default="true">` used in `fluidbootstraptheme` to `<f:defaultCase>`
2. `flux:grid.column` requires `colPos` and it was missing in some instances in the `fluidboostraptheme` extension